# Android code being deleted when trying to copy project into workspace

Tags: android, eclipse, import, ide

so I've been looking around google because I'm having he same problem many people have had when trying to import an Android project into the Eclipse workspace. I saw in one of the posts that I should try to check the copy project into workspace box. My projects are already in the Eclipse workspace folder, they are simply not in my project explorer. So when I check the box and press finish the project gets imported, but all the code is deleted from the src files and xml files... is there any way to undo this? thanks

edit: Im on Windows 7, 64 bit

Comment: what environment are you on ? windows,  mac os or linux

Comment: Add `IDE` to the tags.

Comment: added tag and edited question.